# df.fillna() not working but df.dropna() working

Tags: python, pandas

In my code the df.fillna() method is not working when the df.dropna() method is working. I don't want to drop the column though. What can I do that the fillna() method works?

```
def preprocess_df(df):
for col in df.columns:  # go through all of the columns
    if col != "target":  # normalize all ... except for the target itself!
        df[col] = df[col].pct_change()  # pct change "normalizes" the different currencies (each crypto coin has vastly diff values, we're really more interested in the other coin's movements)
        # df.dropna(inplace=True)  # remove the nas created by pct_change
        df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
        print(df)
        break
        df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)  # scale between 0 and 1.
```

Comment: Try `df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True, axis=1)`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: the NaN does not disappear.

Comment: I've tried with df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True, axis=1) but still the same.

Comment: Error message is: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: @user9468014 Can you please add a sample of your dataframe which has `Nan`?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
df = df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
```

You have to assign it back to df

Comment: This is incorrect. You should not assign back when you use `inplace=True`.

Comment: My bad @jpp, you are correct. Maybe it is something to do with `method='ffill'`? According to pd docs, `ffill` propagates the last valid observation. What if the entire column is NaN s. How does it know what to propagate it with? Perhaps its worth manually telling it what to fill the NaNs with?